# Image preview/thumbnail not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, images, windows-explorer

I'm in the process of setting up a new laptop with Windows 7 Enterprise and I'm having two issues:

1. Image previews/thumbnails are not displaying in Explorer.
2. Most of the files I've copied from my old system have a grey "X" overlay on the icon.

I suspect these issues are related, but I really don't know. As best I can tell the grey "X" has to do with files being archived to tape (?), but I have no idea why this is happening. I've ensured that "Always show icons, never thumbnails" is not set. I've deleted the cached thumbnail files. Still no luck.

Here's a screenshot that illustrates both issues:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: The Little Gray cross shows that the files are archived: 
http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/12/a-list-of-those-little-overlay-icons-in-windows-7/

Comment: I got that far, but what does it mean? I copied these files from another laptop and they show up as archived? Why?

Comment: Okay, how 'bout this. Can anyone tell me how to remove the grey "X"? Removing the A file attribute doesn't do anything...